# Derby DB installed, JAR included, where to locate DB for portability of project?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby, sqljdbc

So I'm new to working with Java databases and I've settled on using Apache Derby. I have it installed on my system and have included the derby.jar in the project buildpath. However, I need this project to be portable (including from Windows to OSX/UNIX) so that the database can be initialized and fully accessed for updating and reading on a device other than my machine.

So my question is, how do I make this happen? Is including the derby.jar file enough or do I need to do something like initialize a database within the project file system or something else? Do I need to specify a certain write location in a class within the project? If it's helpful, I'm using Eclipse IDE.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you asking if you can use the same `derby.jar` on Windows, Mac, and Linux (yes, you can)? Or are you asking where on the user's disk you should put your database folder (you should probably ask your user this question, and put your database where they ask you to put it, but if you need a default, each operating system tends to have its own default storage location).

Comment: @BryanPendleton I'm asking the latter (the former was thrown in there because I wasn't sure if that would be an issue initially due to the different syntax for directory URLs cross platform). I think I'm understanding how to set the default location 
    `String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");`
    `String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/DerbyDB/DBName";`

    `// Set the db system directory.`
    `System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);`

I apologize for the weird code format, having trouble understanding the SO code formatting in comments... first time.

Answer (score 1):

So after some thorough reading I found my own solution, at least in theory (I've not yet finished the project build to try it out). Use this in a Data Access Object (DAO).

As per [John O'Conner](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javadb-141163.html#connecting):

```
private void setDBSystemDir() {
    /* Decide on the db system directory: <userhome>/DerbyDB/DBName/ */
    String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");
    String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/DerbyDB/DBName";

    // Set the db system directory.
    System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);
}
```